# Pandas: Getting fixed number of rows by using loc

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose we have following Dataframe.

```
tempDataframe = 

Col1 Col2
1   2
1   4
2   5
```

After running the following code I expect this result:

```
tempDataframe = tempDataframe.set_index('Col1')
tempDataframe.loc[[1,2]]

Col1 Col2
1    2
1    4
2    5
2    0
```

For each index, there should be at-least **two** results. For entries which has less than two values should return an extra entry with zeros.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How can I get this output without performing iteration? (Each index should return minimum 2 rows )

Comment: since you are not performing iteration I don't understand what your issue is or what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: What about with more than 2?

Comment: in reality **tempDataframe.loc[[1,2]]** will never output above mentioned result. What i can do to achieve it ?.

Comment: @user3483203 for more than 2 just output the original rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case , you need create a helper key by using `cumcount`

```
df['New']=df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df.set_index('New',append=True,inplace=True)
df.unstack(fill_value=0).stack().groupby(level=0).head(2)
Out[436]: 
          Col2
Col1 New      
1    0       2
     1       4
2    0       5
     1       0
```

Comment: Love u !!! :p .. Took me some time to understand it but really an intelligent solution.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you want to use [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with fill_value.